# jQuery Limitation the scope of <script>

Tags: asp.net, jquery

here is the [Manual](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=255&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) and the Code of my again trying to make a fixed rows for a Grid :

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/webtoolkit.jscrollable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/webtoolkit.scrollabletable.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('table').Scrollable(400, 1500);
    });
</script>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="False" AllowSorting="True" OnPreRender="GridView2_PreRender"
        onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated" Width="100%" ondatabound="GridView2_DataBound">
    </asp:GridView>

</asp:Panel>
```

How to Limit the scope of `<Script>` on my div or some area with my GridView.

Now it works for whole page and breaks it out.

(*also I got a question about fixing this script work , but the main trouble is Limitation the scope of `<script>`*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should select only the client `GridView2` table.

You can either get the `ClientID` server-side property to build your selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#<%=GridView2.ClientID%>').Scrollable(400, 1500);
});
```

Or use the [`attributeEndsWith`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('table[id$=GridView2]').Scrollable(400, 1500);
});
```

Comment: thank you ! It helps me. Don't you know how to save vertical scrollbar? because I've got a horizontal scrollbar...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your problem is that your jQuery selector is running on every table, while you want it to run only on the GridView.  The solution is to use a class or id selector, and add that class or ID to the GridView(s).

Either:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#<%=GridView2.ClientID%>').Scrollable(400, 1500);
    });
</script>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="False" AllowSorting="True" OnPreRender="GridView2_PreRender"
    onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated" Width="100%" ondatabound="GridView2_DataBound">
</asp:GridView>
```

or:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.myGridviews').Scrollable(400, 1500);
});

<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" CssClass=".myGridviews" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="False" AllowSorting="True" OnPreRender="GridView2_PreRender"
    onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated" Width="100%" ondatabound="GridView2_DataBound">
</asp:GridView>
```

EDIT: Fixed id, thanks to CMS.